# Cant get ASP.NET Core Web API to work with IIS

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm building an **ASP.NET Core MVC Web Api** application and I'm trying to get it to work with IIS on my own machine. I have read different blogs and tried different things but just can't seem to get it to work... My Winform client just gets a 404 when calling the Web api. Navigating to the site roo via web browser gives me a HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden.

Im running Windows 10 Pro. IIS installed. ASP.NET Core Server Hosting Bundle is installed

I have added the website in IIS. Application pool is set to No Managed Code.
In VS2015 I Publish the website to a local folder. I copy the content of that folder to my website folder where IIS is looking. Then I would expect it to work but it doesn't :(

Here is my setup:

**web.config**

```
  <system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
</handlers>
<directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
<aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%"
      arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%"
      stdoutLogEnabled="true"
      stdoutLogFile=".\logs\aspnetcore-stdout"
      forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
```

**Program.cs**

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var host = new WebHostBuilder()
        .UseKestrel()
        .UseWebRoot("wwwroot")
        .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
        .UseIISIntegration()
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .Build();

    host.Run();
}
```

**StartUp.cs**

```
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }
```

**appsettings.json**

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

**project.json:**

```
    {
    "dependencies": {
    "Business": "1.0.0-*",
    "Data": "1.0.0-*",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.EnvironmentVariables": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Options.ConfigurationExtensions": "1.1.0",
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": "1.1.0"
    },
    "tools": {
    "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.IISIntegration.Tools": "1.1.0-preview4-final"
      },
     "frameworks": {
     "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": [
        "dotnet5.6",
        "portable-net45+win8"
      ]
    }
  },
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true,
    "preserveCompilationContext": true
  },
  "runtimeOptions": {
    "configProperties": {
      "System.GC.Server": true
    }
  },
  "publishOptions": {
    "include": [
      "wwwroot",
      "**/*.cshtml",
      "appsettings.json",
      "web.config"
    ]
  },
  "runtimes": {
    "win10-x64": {}
  },
  "scripts": {
    "postpublish": [ "dotnet publish-iis --publish-folder %publish:OutputPath% --framework %publish:FullTargetFramework%" ]
  }
}
```

**Website in IIS**

[image]

**Application Pool in IIS**

[image]

**Folder structure for website path**
[image]

**My IIS**

[image]

Comment: try pointing to inetpub/wwwroot/mywebapi instead of inetpub/wwwroot/mywebapi/wwwroot

Comment: What are the security settings for the MyWebAPI and www directories?

Comment: Full access to IUSR and IIS_IUSERS on root folder wwwroot and subfolders.
Makes no difference changing path to inetpub/wwwroot/mywebapi. Read somewhere that it has to point to the wwwroot folder within the published folder.

Comment: Ok so I got it to work... But I have NO idea why! Programming in a nutshell :)
I created a new .net Core web project and tested it with IIS. It worked fine so I added a bit more.. and then a bit more and so on, until I had copied everything from my old solution to the new one. And now it works!

Comment: Well done. Did you end up pointing at MyWebAPI or at wwwroot?

Comment: Points to MyWebAPI :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Point IIS to `MyWebAPI` instead of at `MyWebAPI/wwwroot`. Otherwise you will receive an "HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden" error.

Here is a [demo application on GitHub](https://github.com/bigfont/StackOverflow/tree/master/AspNetCorePublishToIIS). It is using the same setup as the app in your answer is using. It worked when I published it to my IIS like this:

```
dotnet publish -o C:\inetpub\wwwroot\sandbox\
```

Comment: Gave it a try but it's not working. Something else must be wrong then.

Comment: What error are you receiving now? I used your exact setup (except for your web.config file) locally and was able to run the site in IIS.

Comment: {"Response status code does not indicate success: 502 (Bad Gateway)."}

Comment: Aha. Different error. :) That's progress.

Comment: @ChristianThoressonDahl I've been able to use your web.config file and make it work locally too. Keep pointing at `MyWebAPI` instead of at `wwwroot`; check your `.\logs\aspnetcore-stdout` files and the IIS logs in the Event Viewer. Try the GitHub demo that I posted for you, as a minimal reproduction. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks guys. I will have a look at the link. I just tried creating an empty project using the regular template. Worked fine with iis of course... So I will try and have a look at whats different between the two projects. Will post my findings..

Comment: Ever find a working answer to this? Same problem you have but getting 404 error (works fine in Visual Studio) - regular DotNetCore 2.1 websites work just fine, only the WEB API does not.